# Extract administrative boundary only data from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, mbtiles

I'm trying to host a map for a selected administrative region. Extracts available on geofabrik similar services, sadly, do not provide extract of this sub-region.

I've extracted administrative boundary shape via Overpass API and tried extracting this using different tools, but none of them helped me achieve what I need:

- protomaps, doesn't support more than 1k indices in a shape
- hotosm, extracts bounding box only
- pmtiles accepts my shape file just fine, but results in bounding box extract

What are my options next?
I'm happy with either dumping region from OSM raw database or extracting region from geofabrik extracts in osm.pbf format